# Internet Explorer Javascript Slideshow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a very strange issue going on here. It's only occurring on Internet Explorer (what a surprise).

Basically I'm trying to fix a site that was given to me after some third-rate developers finished it and obviously did not test on IE.

They've setup a javascript slideshow, now on the pages with the slideshow active, the whole enclosing "body_section" div is being pushed all the way to the left. Have a look for yourselves:

http://sapaconstruction.com.au/sapa/

That's the homepage which floats everything to the left. Now on this page:

http://sapaconstruction.com.au/sapa/?page_id=4

Everything looks normal, so it must have something to do with the javascript slideshow. Here's what the javascript they've written looks like (it's embed on the page).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('homeslideshow').style.display='none';
    $('wrapper').style.display='block';
    var homeslideshow=new TINY.slideshow("homeslideshow");
    window.onload=function(){
        homeslideshow.auto=true;
        homeslideshow.speed=5;
        homeslideshow.init("homeslideshow","image","imgprev","imgnext","imglink");
    }
    </script>
```

Any help with this issue would be amazing, I've wracked my brain for hours trying hacks and margin fixes and things like that.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts, and also, keep the begging out of your questions, please.

Comment: sorry about that, won;t happen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can tell you this.  This site has way more problems than just that.  In looking at the source, there is a div that comes before the html node.  I would first of all fix that, as even in firefox, this is causing some strange things to happen.  As a matter of fact, I think this "ieonly" div is what is causing the issue, as in IE this div becomes the wrapper in the body.  Whoever built this site was not very familiar with cross browser design, and tried to bake in way too many IE hacks.

EDIT:

The problem was IE was in quirks mode due to the lack of a doctype.  The following doctype should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: i've taken out the ieonly div and it still seems to be pushing it to the left, but only in internet explorer

Comment: Okay, I have figured it out.  First of all, the style tag at the beginning of the markup needs to go into the head, again you cannot have anything (except a doctype) before the html tag.  Your problem is IE is in quirks mode, please add a doctype (first line in the document).  Try this: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly